# block callbacks -- when original object is deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm calling my DatabaseManager to save an object created in a viewController like so:

```
  [DatabaseManager addUniqueObject:fooChild key:[fooParent fooChildKey] toObject:self.foo callback:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {


            if (error) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.sendBackgroundTaskId];
                return;
            }


               [self.tableView reloadData];
               [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
            }

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.sendBackgroundTaskId];
        }];
```

`addUniqueObject` is a class method in my DatabaseManager (I'm using Parse as the backend as you can see):

```
 + (void)addUniqueObject:(PFObject*)uniqueObject key:(NSString*)key toObject:(PFObject*)object callback:(void(^)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error))callback {

    if (uniqueObject) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addUniqueObjectToObject"
                           withParameters:@{@"classKey":[object parseClassName],
                                            @"objectId":[object objectId],
                                            @"keyToAdd":key,
                                            @"objectToAddClassKey":[uniqueObject parseClassName],
                                            @"objectToAddId":[uniqueObject objectId],

                                            }
                                    block:^(NSMutableDictionary *results , NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            callback(YES, error);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            callback(NO, error);
                                        }
                                    }];
    }

}
```

1. First question - So if I create this object but then navigate away and thus pop this VC before the save executes, then `self.tableView` or any other property I'm referencing in the completion block is `nil` at this point, correct?
2. Second question - I passed the completion block to the DatabaseManager - does this completion object still exists if the original VC is destroyed? Do I have to check for existence of this block before I execute `callback()`?

This doesn't seem to cause any problems for me, so I hadn't questioned it until now. But I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, your VC won't be deallocated because `self` is captured inside block. If you want it to be deallocated, you should write something like this:

   ```
   __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // we don't increase retain count here
   [DatabaseManager addUniqueObject:fooChild key:[fooParent fooChildKey] toObject:self.foo callback:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       __strong typeof(self) self = weakSelf;
      // if weakSelf is still not deallocated, it will be retained until block finishes
   ```

   consider using [@strongify/@weakify](http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html) instead of this code snippet.
2. Yes it is. `callback` is retained by block you passing to `callFunctionInBackground:withParameters:block:`, so it won't be released until block is executed. If you are sure that noone will call yout function with `callback:nil`, then you don't need to check it's still exists in completion block.